Heisenberg and Dyzaloskinkii Moriya Interaction
The Heisenberg hamiltonian is $H= J\vec{S_i}\cdot\vec{S_j}$ whilst the Dzyaloshinkii Moriya Interaction is $H=\vec D\cdot\left(\vec{S_i}\times\vec{S_j}\right)$. But how do these equations come about? How are they derived? How is that one is a dot product and the other is a cross product?

Wikipedia has a derivation of the DMI.

How is that one is a dot product and the other is a cross product? There are a limited number of ways to construct a rotationally-invariant Hamiltonian from two vectors.
